# Assigning a negative hexadecimal literal value as a long

Tags: c#, literals

In VB, the following assignments below have negative values:

```vb
Dim a As Long = &HEFCDAB89
Dim b As Long = &H98BADCFE
```

Assigning the same hexadecimal values in C# does not result in the same values:

```
long a = 0xEFCDAB89;
long b = 0x98BADCFE;
```

How can I assign negative hexadecimal values in C# as it is in VB?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [L and UL literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664674%28v=VS.71%29.aspx):

```
long b = 0xEFCDAB89L; //signed long
long c = (long)0x98BADCFEUL; //unsigned long
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any tricks to tell the compiler that you want to specify a negative hex literal, I'm not sure that's really possible.  I believe your only option is to cast the `ulong` literal to a `long`.  It will have to be done in an unchecked context.  It is still a value known at compile time so no actual casting code will be generated.

```
long value = unchecked((long)0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFE);
// value == -2L
```

Note that in VB, `&HEFCDAB89` and `&H98BADCFE` are actually `Integer` literals.  They just happened to be promoted to a `Long`.  To specify a `Long` literal, you must include the suffix `L`.  So you assignments would have to be:

```vb
Dim a As Long = &HFFFFFFFFEFCDAB89L ' these are actually long literals now
Dim b As Long = &HFFFFFFFF98BADCFEL
```